# Incluir dados no BD em Java

Tags: java

Estou seguindo um curso a distância, só que estou com problemas na hora de incluir o registro. Ele não inclui, mas também não apresenta nenhum erro, e pelos exemplos do professor que eu segui, não deu certo. Também já vi várias vídeoaulas na Internet e apostilas, mas mesmo assim continua sem incluir no BD.

OBS: Já testei a conexão com o BD e está tudo Ok.

**Classe Conexão com o BD:**

```
    public Statement stm; // Prepara e realiza pesquisas no BD.
    public ResultSet rs; // Armazena o resultado de uma pesquisa passada para o STM.
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // Identificar o BD.
    private String caminho = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/alunos"; // Seta o local do BD.
    private String usuario = "root";
    private String senha = "";
    public Connection conn; // Realiza a conexao com o BD.


    public void conexao(){ // Metodo que realizar conexao com o BD.
        try {
            System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver); // Seta a propriedade do driverde conexao
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha); // Realizao conexao com o BD.
            System.out.println("Conectado com Sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void desconecta(){ // Metodo para fechar conexao BD.
        try {
            conn.close(); // Fecha conexao.
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Classe que recebe os métodos:**

```
public class Alunos {

    ConexaoAluno conecta = new ConexaoAluno();  // Variavel global.

    public void incluir(){

        conecta.conexao();

        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("insert into alunos (endereco, cep, cidade, estado, pais) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, "Av. Mantiqueira");
            pst.setString(2, "74565-410");
            pst.setString(3, "Goiania");
            pst.setString(4, "GO");
            pst.setString(5, "Brasil");
            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.print("Inserido com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Classe que chama os métodos e executa:**

```
public class TestaAluno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Alunos al = new Alunos();

        al.incluir();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está gerenciando a conexão e o `PreparedStatement` de maneiras adequadas, e as está largando abertas. Use a sintaxe *try-with-resources* do Java 7+ para resolver isso da forma mais simples.

Faça assim:

```
public class ConexaoAluno {
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String caminho = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/alunos";
    private static final String usuario = "root";
    private static final String senha = "";

    static {
        System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver);
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Erro fatal. Não foi possível achar o driver do MySQL", e);
        }
    }

    public Connection conexao() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

```
public class Alunos {

    private static final String INCLUIR_SQL = "INSERT INTO alunos (endereco, cep, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private final ConexaoAluno conecta;

    public Alunos() {
        conecta = new ConexaoAluno();
    }

    public void incluir() {
        try (Connection conn = conecta.conexao(),
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(INCLUIR_SQL))
        {
            pst.setString(1, "Av. Mantiqueira");
            pst.setString(2, "74565-410");
            pst.setString(3, "Goiania");
            pst.setString(4, "GO");
            pst.setString(5, "Brasil");
            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.print("Inserido com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TestaAluno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alunos al = new Alunos();
        al.incluir();
    }
}
```

E outra coisa, você já deve ter visto que manter atributos públicos é uma má prática de programação, não é? Então, por favor, não faça isso.

Ah sim, e [certifique-se que o JAR do Connector do MySQL](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar) está no seu classpath.

Comment: *Medalha 'olhos de águia' desbloqueada com sucesso.*

Comment: Realmente nao tinha atentado para os atributos publicos, apesar de ja ter visto isto no meu curso. Agora estou com erro:`
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/alunos
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 at br.com.curso.ConexaoAluno.conexao(ConexaoAluno.java:18)
 at br.com.curso.Alunos.incluir(Alunos.java:18)
 at br.com.curso.TestaAluno.main(TestaAluno.java:8)`

Comment: @ItalloFreire Atualizei a minha resposta como `Class.forName`. Que erro que dá agora?

Comment: No **debug** ele fala que contem erro na linha 17:
`throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Nao foi possivel achar o Driver do SQL." + e);`

Comment: @ItalloFreire Bingo! Era exatamente o erro que eu esperava que daria. O seu problema é que o jar do mysql-connector não está no seu classpath. Coloquei o link para download no final da resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa so que eu fui em bibliotecas e add o mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.zp dentro do **java build path**, isso nao resolveria meu problema ?

Comment: @ItalloFreire Tem que ser `.jar`. Se colocar `.zip` não vai dar certo. De qualquer forma, você consegue ver o que a sua IDE gera exatamente ao executar o programa?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Perfeito nao tinha atentado para esse detalhe. Muito obg, ajudou muito

Comment: Ué... não deveria ter o `:3306` no caminho do banco?